# Android activity intent

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I have developed the android Quiz app. Totally 5 screens. I have closed the app in 3rd screen.Then started the app once again, the app displayed the 3rd screen by default. But i need 1st screen.

Can anyone give the solution for this.

Comment: When you say close, do u mean u pressed the HOME button?

Comment: if you use home button then the activity will start with the same screen. override back button and come to the main screen by finishing the activity

Comment: How you close your application ?

Answer (score 1):

when you press `Close Button` call this  code

```
finish();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

when you press home button , actually app don't get close. it goes in background so whenever you restart your app again it showed the last screen which was open. however you can use

```
    public void onRestart() {
   super.onRestart();
}
```

In this method you can call first activity using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`.

however if you close app by back button , it will restart from first screen so there would not be any problem in it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call **finish();** method on your activity 2 and 3 to destroy them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a flag on your Main Activity (Launcher) so that it clears the top when launched again. You can do this in the manifest file. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setFlags(int)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void onBackPressed() {

Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
        Default.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
}
```